# Name a Pandas Dataframe after a defined variable from a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists in python:

```
path = ['users/documents', 'users/desktop',....,.....,....]

dfnames = ['ABCDocuments', 'ABCFiles',...,...,...]
```

I am running a loop to take all .csv files in each of the `path` locations and passing them into individual dataframes.

In my loop I would like to create a dataframe named after the corresponding iteration from `dfnames`.

My code so far is:

```
for idx, filepath in enumerate(filepathlist):
    csvfiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.csv'))
    dataframes = []  
    for csvfile in csvfiles:
        df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
        dataframes.append(df)

    dfnames[idx] = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
```

I am getting an error. Is there any way that I can name the dataframe the resulting string from `dfnames[idx]` ?

I essentially want all of the .csv files from `users/documents` into one dataframe called `ABCDocuments` and likewise for all other items in my lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just to use a name from `dfnames` to reference a dataframe you can simply use a dictionary to group all dataframes under any keys you want:

```
dfs = {}
dfs[dfnames[idx]] = dframe
```

This is the correct way to do this.

If you want to get variables with names from `dfnames` to reference specific `dframe` you can assign them to locals although this isn't advised, this is how
you would assigned a variable named with string content of `dfnames[1]`, (lets assume `dfnames[1]='ABCFiles'`) to the locals scope and give it a value of `dframe`:

```
locals()[dfnames[1]] = dframe
```

after this typing `ABCFiles` in the same scope will reference the variable `dframe`